# Umbraco Overriding or extending default membership provider

Tags: umbraco

I want to use a different provider in Umbraco 6.1.6, e.g. I have this

```
    <membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.members.UmbracoMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Website" passwordFormat="Hashed" umbracoApprovePropertyTypeAlias="isActive" umbracoLastLoginPropertyTypeAlias="loginDate" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

but I want to use this

```
<membership defaultProvider="TechBureauMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="TechBureauMembershipProvider" type="TechBureau.Web.providers.TechBureauMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Website" passwordFormat="Hashed" umbracoApprovePropertyTypeAlias="isActive" umbracoLastLoginPropertyTypeAlias="loginDate"/>
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Because I want to override the ResetPassword password function to not do anything.

```
public class TechBureauMembershipProvider : UmbracoMembershipProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Overriding this so that it does nothing, reseting a password to a random password isn't cool for anyone.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <param name="answer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        return string.Empty; //base.ResetPassword(username, answer);
    }
}
```

But the problem is the Members tab doesn't load if I do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David is on the right path but I don't believe reflection overwrite is necessary here.
Change the type of `UmbracoMembershipProvider` but leave the name the same.

```
        <membership defaultProvider="TechBureauMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="2880">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="TechBureau.Web.providers.TechBureauMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
            <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
```

Comment: Ah, right, that makes so much sense right now, I will try that out, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the "umbraco.cms\businesslogic\member\Member.cs" file hardcodes the provider name to:

`public static readonly string UmbracoMemberProviderName = "UmbracoMembershipProvider";`

So you might have to override the function using reflection.

Comment: No, see the other answer, just keep the same name.